# Limiting X axis in Dash

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, plotly-dash

I have a cryptocurrency ticker that saves the data in PostgreSQL Table. I used Live-update of Dash to get the data from PostgreSQL and it is working. My problem is since the database has 2 days' worth of data, I can't see the latest as it keeps refreshing and it keeps showing the first 10 on the x-axis. I would like to know if there's a way to limit the x-axis so that the graph will show the 10 latest data from the database.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import dash
import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go

from collections import deque


MAX_POINTS_TO_SHOW = 15

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='graph-update',
        disabled = False,
        interval=1*5000,    
        n_intervals=0,
        max_intervals=-1,
    )
])

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph(n):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/Cryptocurrency')
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql("select * from \"cryptocurrency\"", conn)
        # fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df["time"], y=df["bitcoin_php"], mode="lines+markers", name="lines+markers"))
        time = df["time"]
        php = df["bitcoin_php"]
        data = go.Scatter(x = time, y=php, name="Scatter", mode="lines+markers")
    
    return {'data': [data],'layout' : go.Layout(xaxis=dict(range=[min(time[:-10]),max(time)]),
                                                yaxis=dict(range=[min(php),max(php)]),)}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Nearly impossible to offer a helpful answer without having a snippet of the data. We have no way of seeing how the data is formatted.